# Firebase modules not working, even tho imported correctly - Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have imported firebase from CDN in the index.html
and am using the functions from it in game.js

Index.html

```
    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-analytics.js";
        import { getDatabase, ref, onValue, update } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-database.js"
        import { getAuth, signInAnonymously, onAuthStateChanged } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-auth.js"
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
            //myconfig
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
        const auth = getAuth()
        const database = getDatabase()
    </script>


    <script type="module" src="game.js"></script>
```

game.js

```
//sign in user anonymysly
signInAnonymously(auth)

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user
        console.log(user.uid)

        onValue(ref(database, 'boards/players'), (snapshot) => {...})
```

These signInAnonymously function is the first one that uses firebase in the game.js file and returns as error

This is my first project with the new firebase module way.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code) --- That also gives you a change to add the exact error message and stack trace you get.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Without specifics, we can only be guessing (which is a waste of everyone's time).

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: signInAnonymously  -  
This is the exact error